# Doesn't vector bosons enter in the formula for the calculation of beta function coefficients?

Tags: gauge-theory, renormalization, symmetry-breaking

It is a well established result that, for a popular set of conventions, the lowest order $\beta$ function coefficient is calculated as

$$
b=-\frac{11}{3}C_2(G)+\frac{4}{3}\kappa S_2(F)+\frac{1}{6}\eta S_2(S).
$$

Of these terms, the first one is the one responsible for taking into account the gauge bosons contributions -- $C_2(G)$ is the group-theoretical quadratic Casimir of the gauge group.

However, imagine that we are studying a spontaneously broken theory with Higgs mechanism and pattern $G \to H$, with the breaking occurring at scale $\Lambda$. Suppose, for instance, that $\text{dim}(G)=\text{dim}(H)+5$ and that I want to calculate $b$ on this theory to calculate the running of some gauge coupling for energies lesser than $\Lambda$.

In this case, there are $5$ vector bosons that now are not in the adjoint representation of some gauge group but may even carry charges of various group factors. The immediate example would be if we wanted to calculate (by this method) the $b$ for the electron charge at energies lower than that of the breaking $\text{SM}\to U(1)_\text{EM}$: here we have 2 vector bosons charged under $U(1)$, being $W_\mu^{\pm}$.

In this case, I think that there would be indeed no contributions since they cannot contribute to a correction of the $e$ vertex, but how general is this? I cannot see how this generalizes to a more complex non-abelian lower group (if it is correct). Do massive charged (in the general sense) vectors on spontaneously broken renormalizable theories never contribute to the running?